# how to write below query in joomla model class using joomla2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

> select es.* from  `g5ch3_empstatus_objects` as `es` inner join(select 
>   statuscreator,statuscreatorid,max(created)as maxcreated, ustatus from 
>   `g5ch3_empstatus_objects` where statuscreator='user->name' group by
>   statuscreator )s on es.statuscreator=s.statuscreator and
>   es.created=s.maxcreated

How to write this query in Joomla model class am using joomla2.5

I've tried in this way but i get empty result set:

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);    
$subquery = $db->getQuery(true);
$subquery->select('max(created) as maxcreated')
-> from ('#_empstatus_objects');
$query->select(
        'es.id as id,' .
        'es.statuscreator,' .
        'es.statuscreatorid,' .
        'es.created,' .
        'es.ustatus'
);
$query->from ('#__empstatus_objects as es'.$subquery.$where)
-> group('statuscreator');

$superadmin = $this->access_superuser($user->id);
if(!$superadmin){
    $query->where ('statuscreatorid='.$user->id);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/2.5 and take a look at the "Selecting Records from Multiple Tables" section.